# Which type withRouter return?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript. I have a React HOC, which use withRouter. Eslint show me error "Missing return type on function.". I can't understand how to describe retun type for filterRedirectHOC function.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import LocalStore from '../../../store/localStore';
import getMutateFilterStorageObjectFn from './mutation/getMutateFilterStorageObjectFn';
import getFilterSubmitURL from '../../Filter/commonFilterFn';

interface IFilterName {
  filterName: string;
}

const filterRedirectHOC = <P extends { [key: string]: unknown }>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>,
  filterName: string
) =>
  withRouter(({ ...props }: P & RouteComponentProps) => {
    const { location, history } = props;

    const mutateFilterStorageObjectFn: any = getMutateFilterStorageObjectFn(filterName);

    // const url = new URL(location);
    // console.log("hocComponent -> location", location)

    // if (!url.getParamValue('filter')) {
    if (!location.search) {
      const localStore = new LocalStore();

      const filterData = localStore.getFilterData(filterName, mutateFilterStorageObjectFn);

      if (Object.keys(filterData).length > 0) {
        const urlString = getFilterSubmitURL(filterData, filterName, location);
        if (location.pathname !== urlString) {
          history.push(urlString);
          return null;
        }
      }
    }

    const newProps = { ...props, filterName };
    return <WrappedComponent {...(newProps as P & IFilterName)} />;
  });

export default filterRedirectHOC;
```

This information vscode show when i hover to "export default **filterRedirectHOC**", but i can't convert this to the correct type.

```
const filterRedirectHOC: <P extends {
    [key: string]: unknown;
}>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>, filterName: string) => React.ComponentClass<Omit<P & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, unknown>, "location" | ... 2 more ... | "staticContext"> & {}, any> & WithRouterStatics<...>
```

Comment: WrappedComponent is a component which takes props P & RouteComponentProps & IFilterProps.  You create a component which requires only P.

Answer (score 0):

The general signature for this type of HOC is that it takes a component which requires a generic set of props `P` and returns a component which no longer requires any of the props which we are adding.  Basically it should look something like:

```
export function withSomething<P extends AddedProps>(
    component: React.ComponentType<P>,
): React.ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof AddedProps>>;
```

The definition of `withRouter` is a more complex version of that:

```
export function withRouter<P extends RouteComponentProps<any>, C extends React.ComponentType<P>>(
    component: C & React.ComponentType<P>,
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof RouteComponentProps<any>> & WithRouterProps<C>> & WithRouterStatics<C>;
```

But I'm really bashing my head against a wall here because I cannot write a return type that typescript will accept.  It keeps giving me errors that something is not assignable when to me it seems obvious that it is!  It's not accepting that `Exclude<keyof P, KeyNames>` is the same thing as `keyof Omit<P, KeyNames>` even though they [both evaluate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArIN4FgBQBIAC2AGcwB7KATwC5k4RKBuXPYsgWwjCJAHNbSUUL2Y4AvrlxhKABxQBRZAF5k8gB4IANgFcAJhAA8AawiUyMNABpkAIiKkKlG8gA%20tzWQRwwwMiGduNuzeCAQBtqTewAgAwn6QamA2AHyMyAD06cgQAG5wOt4QxMjkERxcPLw2UrIoAPLKyCZmFnXswGAGqNZ2JORU4TYeXj5%20g8FgoYORPrHxEIkpaZnZeQWQxaU2bJzcwjZAA) to the same thing.

I give up.  Tell ESLint to ignore this one and move on with your life.

I tried breaking it up into two pieces and the piece which contains all your logic is straightforward and easy.  We give it a component and a filter name and returns a component which takes all of the same props minus `filterName`.  Here we are expecting that the `RouteComponentProps` have already been added.

```
const applyLogic = <P extends RouteComponentProps & IFilterName>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>,
  filterName: string
): React.FunctionComponent<Omit<P, "filterName">> => 
    (props: Omit<P, "filterName">) => {
        /** your code form inside withRouter goes here **/
    };
```

The part that is infuriating is trying to wrap this in `withRouter`:

```
const filterRedirectHOC = <P extends RouteComponentProps & IFilterName>(
  WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>,
  filterName: string
): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof IFilterName | keyof RouteComponentProps<any>>> => 
    withRouter(applyLogic(WrappedComponent, filterName));
```

The typescript validator is trying to validate in an iterative way, and gets an error from this chain:

```
Type 'Exclude<keyof P, "filterName" | "history" | "location" | "match" | "staticContext">' is not assignable to type 'keyof Omit<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "filterName">>, "history" | "location" | "match" | "staticContext">'.
    Type 'keyof P' is not assignable to type 'keyof Omit<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "filterName">>, "history" | "location" | "match" | "staticContext">'.
      Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof Omit<Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "filterName">>, "history" | "location" | "match" | "staticContext">'.
```

It's the way they are evaluated piece by piece which is causing the problem because [I swear they are the same](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArIN4FgBQBIAC2AGcwB7KATwC5k4RKBuXPYsgWwjCJAHNbSUUL2b4YwADaQoAOTicBYIX1EBfXLjCUADigCiyALzI9ADwQSArgBMIAHgDWESmRhoANMgBE4qdDmcXsgAPt5EpBSUQaFeEmQIcGDAZCDR3uyJCARpXqSJwAgAwimQpmBeAHyMyAD0NchauiZG3myc3MJemjooAPItTi5uvezAYHaoBQ4TnmYWNvaDrh7evtIBEJUVnl7h5FQ5cQlJKTkZYFk5eUlFJRBlldV1DT3I-ca5HFw8vF5AA).